# Clockwork gem is trying to access development db in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clockwork

I am trying to start the clockwork with following command `sudo bundle exec clockwork config/clock.rb` in production. But it throws the following error
`ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]`.
It works correctly in local. We have Puma server and JRuby setup in server.

Comment: please post your `database,yml`

Comment: also did you add `require './config/boot'`
`require './config/environment'`

Comment: What is the status of RAILS_ENV ? Try to add RAILS_ENV=production at the start of your command.

Answer (score 2):

Add the RAILS_ENV variable:

```
RAILS_ENV=production sudo bundle exec clockwork config/clock.rb
```

Or, set the RAILS_ENV variable in your `.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export RAILS_ENV=production' >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then exit the shell, and login again. From then on, clockwork (and all other rails related things) should be in production mode. You can use the command you were using originally.